# How set line-buffering in FileHandler of python logging module?

Tags: python, logging

I would like to be able to watch the messages in the log file. But it doesn't even appear until the script exits. For example, in the arguments of the `open()` function, you can specify a `buffering=1`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.